# Cannot locate document specification because multiple schemas matched the message type while using a pipeline

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have 7 schemas lacking namespace and with the same root node. I know this results in an error when using the standard xml pipeline. So i made 7 receive pipelines that that have the schema as "Document Schema" (as described here [wordpress](https://srirambiztalks.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/cannot-locate-document-specification-because-multiple-schemas-matched-the-message-type/) in solution 3). I have done this before and then had it work but this time, it remained giving me the same error.

I tried looking into what could cause the error but haven't found anything yet and google searches come up with the problem of not using a custom receive pipeline.

I "solved" the issue by enabling AllowUnrecognisedMessage on the receivepipeline but i am not finding it a satisfying solution.

Comment: Most likely, you just missed one.  There's nothing at all unusual about what you're describing.

Comment: You may want to consider having a pipeline with a Add Namespace pipeline component and adding a namespace to your schemas, otherwise you will encounter this issue more often.